# How do i pass constant values from tomcat to war file(i.e. based upon spring-boot )?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

> After lot of online search & tried lot of experiments. finally i
>   didn't get any of the link which can full-fill my requirement, so
>   finally I choose this platform.

**Note :** `I am using Spring-Boot Maven Project & Tomcat 7.0.62 version & JDK 7.`

First of all I was using `Embedded Tomcat & produce .Jar` and i was passing extra `dynamic parameter` to `.jar` using `command line argument`.

Now, scenario has been changed. My `.Jar` file will be converts to `.war` file also we have `excluded Embedded Tomcat` **i.e. not embedded Tomcat.**

Now i want to pass `same list of command-line argument` to my Spring-Boot project's `.war file from outside.` something like **from tomcat**.

*any help appreciate.*

Comment: if anyone looking out for solution, pls have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53297330/1131967

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options in a servlet container/application server:

1. Use system properties
2. Use init parameters
3. Use JNDI

They'll all be available via Spring's `Environment` so will work pretty much as it you'd passed them in via the command line.