# how to package the springboot application with dynamic end points on application.properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have 1 spring boot application. In this application i have configured 1 eCommerce system as elastic path(Configure the end point url of elastic path in application.properties file). Now i have to give my spring boot application to some other guys. which will be deploy on tomcat server. I don't want to give the source code. So i can make the war file but now problem is that they have their own elastic path eCommerce and they wants to configure their own eCommerce.

I want to externalize some properties which will override the existing property.

My springboot application have 2 modules : 
1) elasticpath module which is having elasticpath-application.properties
2) salesforce - salesforce-application.properties

Now i have to externalize "C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.29\conf\ep-external.properties" file which will override the existing property. Now problem is that @PropertySource is loading in last position. So my external file is not able to override the property.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties", "classpath:elasticpath-application.properties", "classpath:salesforce-application.properties")
public class SpringBootDemo extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements CommandLineRunner {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringBootDemo.class);
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        //application = application.properties("file:C:\\apache-tomcat-8.5.29\\conf\\ep-external.properties");
        return application.sources(SpringBootDemo.class);
    }

    @Override
       public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
           this.servletContext = servletContext;
           super.onStartup(servletContext);
       }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDemo.class, args);
    }   

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes absolutely possible. Basically what you need is changing the property value as needed without changing jar/war 

**Passing command line args for jar** 
Package your spring boot application as jar and put the external application.properties file at any location and pass on the same location as command line argument as below :

```
 java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=file:<property_file_location>
```

This will pick up the external properties.

**Passing command-line/dynamic args for war** 
1. Extend the SpringBootServletInitializer as below

```
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    private ServletContext servletContext;
    public static void main(String[] args){SpringApplication.run(DemoApp.class,args);}
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        builder = builder.properties("test.property:${test_property:defaultValue}");
        return builder.sources(DemoApp.class)
   }
   @Override
   public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
       this.servletContext = servletContext;
       super.onStartup(servletContext);
   }
}
```

2. Access the property as usual like below anywhere you want :

   @Value("${test.property}")
3. Before starting tomcat set the env variable named **test_property**. that's it

Additionally:

You can pass on the property like below as well if you want to supply complete file as external file.

```
.properties("spring.config.location:${config:null}")
```

Further reading about externalized configuration : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Thanks bittu for quick reply. We need to deploy this on tomcat server. So i think we can deploy only war not jar on tomcat server.

Comment: Ah Right. SpringBootApplicationBuilder.addCommandLineProperties will allow you to do that. Configuring env variable(config path or any property) and reading the same at run time then setting the same via above mentioned method should be helpful.

Comment: Thanks bittu. Can you please help me with an example?

Comment: Thanks bittu. I updated my question. Please read again.
My springboot application have 2 modules : 1) elasticpath module which is having elasticpath-application.properties 2) salesforce - salesforce-application.properties

Now i have to externalize "C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.29\conf\ep-external.properties" file which will override the existing property. Now problem is that @PropertySource is loading in last position. So my external file is not able to override the property.

Comment: elasticpath-application.properties should be replaced by external ep-external.properties. Is this what you want ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183651/discussion-between-bittu-and-monty).

Comment: Thanks Bittu. SpringApplicationBuilder.properties(Properties) works for me